# Hide element with CSS in WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress, hide

I have a WP page where I want to hide an element.

On page inspection I find following

HTML

```
<button type="submit" name="add-to-cart" onmouseover=";" onmouseout=";" onload=";" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt  gpls_rfq_set gpls_rfq_css" value="1272" style="display: inline-block">Buy Now</button>
```

Getting Rule as

```
element.style {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

I want change it to

```
<button type="submit" name="add-to-cart" onmouseover=";" onmouseout=";" onload=";" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt  gpls_rfq_set gpls_rfq_css" value="1272" style="display: none">Buy Now</button>
```

to hide the Buy Now button. I tried multiple CSS combination but there is no output.

Comment: What CSS combinations did you try, and how did you implement them?

Answer (score 0):

You can write

```
style="display: none!important"
```

Perhaps somewhere there are styles whose priority is higher, otherwise you will make this one more priority than the rest